# ESXi 6.7 Connect two VM's on ESXi and connect them using router

Tags: routing, vmware-esxi, router

I have an ESXi host installed on a VMware workstation.
On the ESXi, I have two Ubuntu virtual machines and 1 freesco router.

I want to connect both the Ubuntu virtual machines via the router. The virtual machines are on different networks. I've set the static IP's of both the virtual machines so that they are on a different network.

Freesco router config:

[image: link]

ESXi host:

[image: link]

VM1 Static IP: 192.168.204.2

VM2 Static IP: 10.10.10.2

Switch topology:
[image: link]

VM1 settings:
[image: link]

Portgroups:
[image: link]

Both the VM's are connected to same portgroup i.e "connect" and same switch "newSwitch".

I want to connect both the VM's using router. How can I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! The question is overly broad as is. Please [edit] your question and share as much information as you can, like how are the ESXi hosts connected? How is the network configured? Also, please see [ask] and [tour].

Comment: Your screenshot of the ESXi interface shows nothing relevant. The most important part is your network structure, your virtual switches, portgroups, which VM is connected to which portgroup etc.

Comment: I think it might be really useful to add a screenshot of your current https://example.com/ui/host/networking/portgroups perhaps ?

Comment: @Tolsadus done, Sir.

Comment: There is nothing special with VMs or ESXi hosts regarding routing. You require connectivity for each VM (via the port group) to the router and across the router to remote networks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a lab setup to have a play with routing? It looks like your router only has a single port in VMWare, even though the router screenshot suggests two interfaces.

I would expect to see two ports in use for the router, plus 1 for each of the other VMs. If the router is showing both interfaces are up then you should be ready to play.

If you have everything in the same port group it's like the same hub in the real world, so you could have direct communication between VM1 and VM2 if you goof, which may not be helpful for learning the router.

A suggested  alternative is to put one of your VMs in a new portgroup and set a VLAN ID to between 2 and 4094 (if at work and this can connect to a real network check with the admins what IDs are free) and then have your router put one interface on each portgroup. Then VM1 and VM2 should not be able to communicate any other way apart from via the router. You could also create a new vswitch without a physical interface and put the new port switch on there and not have to mess with VLAN IDs.